# Android action bar with tabs and list

Tags: android, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock, android-theme

I'm trying to create an activity with action bar tabs and a list similar to the tweetlanes app:

[image]

I have read that the action bar only supports tabs or list nav, not  both simultaneously. Is there any way to have both? A possible alternative would be to roll my own tabs but I'm not keen on that as i have several tabs so would also have to implement the scrolling behaviour.

Thanks

David

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am pretty sure tweetlanes isn't using the ActionBar tabs since the tabs do not have a seperator. I would say these are the [ViewPageIndicator](http://www.viewpagerindicator.com) tabs from Jake Wharton. So you can use them and simultaniously use the list navigation.

Comment: Yup, it's definitely a ViewPager-like component.